# Android: how to stop animation for a gif image button when pressed in Java?

Tags: java, android, animated-gif

I've this variable:

```
GifImageButton buttonGifImage = new GifImageButton(this);
```

I added it an animated gif:

```
buttonGifImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gifImage);
```

When I load this code, I see the animation. I want to stop the animation when I press on this button. I tried this but it didn't work:

```
buttonGifImage.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_BUTTON_PRESS || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            // Here I would like to stop the animation
            // I want to display the same image but without animating
            buttonGifImage.setFreezesAnimation(true); //not working
            buttonGifImage.clearAnimation(); //not working
        }
    }
}
```

**Is there a good way to stop the animation?** (considering I would like to activate the animation again).

**Or must I create a png image from this gif image and call setBackgroundResource with this png..?**

I'm trying to avoid the saving of 2 images(gif and png) for play\stop animated gif..

**======== EDIT ========**

**my dependencies:**

```
    dependencies {
        compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.+'
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
    }
```

**my repositories:**

```
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots" }
    }
```

Comment: Which library you use for GifImageButton?

Comment: I added EDIT to the question. If it doesn't answer your question, can you please tell me how I check it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use the `getDrawable()` method to get the `GifDrawable` object and call the `stop()` method:

`((GifDrawable)buttonGifImage.getDrawable()).stop()`

or since you have setup as background resource:

`buttonGifImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gifImage);`

use:  `((GifDrawable)buttonGifImage.getBackground()).stop()`

Comment: tried and it crashes because of: "null".stop();
inheritance:

    GifImageButton : ImageButton : ImageView : View

Comment: Change `getDrawable()` to `getBackground()`